# Only drawing contours that exist over several frames to remove flickering

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been researching here and the rest of the web for over a week now and am unable to come up with anything.

I'm coding using C++ and opencv on linux.

I have this video in black and white of a cloud chamber (http://youtu.be/40wnB8ukI7s). I want to draw contours around the moving particle tracks. Currently I'm using findContours and drawContours; however, it draws contours around all of the white pixels, including the ones that quickly appear and disappear. I don't want to draw contours around my background, the flickering white pixels.

My problem is that the background is also moving so background subtraction doesn't work. Is there a way to:

a) only draw a contour if it exists roughly in the same location over several frames

b) remove a white pixel if it doesn't exist for multiple frames (probably at least 4 or 5 frames)

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Edit: Code for comparing two frames (firstFrame and secondFrame)

```
Vec3b frameColour;
    Vec3b frameColour2;
    for (int x = 0; x < firstFrame.cols; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < firstFrame.rows; y++){
            frameColour = firstFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
            frameColour2 = secondFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y));
            if(frameColour == white && frameColour2 == white){
                secondFrameAfter.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = white;
            }else{
                secondFrameAfter.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = black;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement your idea:

```
For each frame do:
    For each white pixel do:
        If the pixels in the neigbourhood of the last N frames are *mostly* white
            Set the current pixel to white
        Else
            Set the current pixel to black
```

The neigbourhood can be defined as a 3x3 mask around the pixel.
*Mostly* refers to an appropriate threshold, let's say 80% of the N frames should support (be white) the pixel position. 
[image: The red pixel is the current pixel (x,y) and the green pixels are its neigbourhood.]
The red pixel is the current pixel (x,y) and the green pixels are its neigbourhood.
Comparing the neigbouring pixel of a pixel (x,y) can be achieved as follows:

```
const int MASK_SIZE = 3;    
int numberOfSupportingFrames = 0;
for(int k = 0; k < N; k++)
{
    Mat currentPreviousFrame = previousFrames.at(k); 
    bool whitePixelAvailable = false;
    for(int i = x-(MASK_SIZE/2); i < x+(MASK_SIZE/2) && !whitePixelAvailable; i++)
    {
        for(int j = y-(MASK_SIZE/2); j < y+(MASK_SIZE/2) && !whitePixelAvailable; j++)
        {                           
            if(currentPreviousFrame.at<Vec3b>(Point(i, j)) == white)
            {
                whitePixelAvailable = true;
                numberOfSupportingFrames++;
            }
        }           
    }
}
if((float)numberOfSupportingFrames / (float)N > 0.8)
    secondFrameAfter.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = white;
else
    secondFrameAfter.at<Vec3b>(Point(x, y)) = black;
```

The previous frames are stored inside `std::vector previousFrames`.
The algorithm checks the spatio-temporal neigbourhood of the pixel (x,y). The outer loop iterates over the neigbouring frames (temporal neigbourhood), while the inner two loops iterate over the neigbouring eight pixels (spatial neighbourhood). If there is a white pixel in the current spatial neighbourhood, this previous frame *supports* the current pixel (x,y). At the end it is checked if there are enough frames supporting the current pixel (80% of the previous frames should contain at least on white pixel in the 8-neigbourhood).
This code should be nested inside your two for-loops with some modifications (variable names, border handling).

Comment: I get how I can compare a pixel in one frame to a pixel in the same location in the previous frame. I've tried comparing with four frames and there isn't much improvement because there is overall movement of the pixels. (I edited my original question with code comparing two frames.) My question is how do I go about comparing neighbourhoods of pixels?